# Cloud Functions triggers twice

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem with Cloud Functions.

I am making a reservation system.
When an admin accepts a reservation, I make this call on the client:

```
reservationRef.update({
  handled: true,
  lastHandledBy: AUTH.currentUser.uid,
  timestamp: TIMESTAMP
})
```

Here is how the whole reservation looks like:

```
roomId: number
address: string
name: string
tel: string
message: string
email: string
from: number
to: number
timestamp: date
lastHandledBy: string
handled: boolean
adults: number
children: number
```

In Cloud Functions, I have a function that triggers when the reservation is updated, so I can send a confirmation e-mail to the user. It looks like this:

```
exports.reservationChanged = reservationRef
       .onUpdate(({before, after}, {params: {reservationId}}) => {
         before = before.data()
         after = after.data()
         // Reservation accepted
         if (!before.handled && after.handled) {
           return email.reservationAccepted(reservationId, after)
         }
       }
```

For some reason though, it is triggered twice and sends two e-mails, and I don't know why. I update the reservation with a simple `.update()`

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is `reservation` in the first bit of code?  What exactly is `reservationRef` in the second bit?

Comment: Sorry, both should be `reservationRef`, and it is the same as for example `firebase.database().ref("reservations/"+reservationId)`
So the reference point in the database, where the update/change is happening

Comment: Are you sure you're only calling `.update()` once?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to update your code to be more specific about the values whose definitions are not shown?

Comment: @Colin yes, I am sure. and Doug Stevenson, I updated the question now.

Comment: Is it possible that `before = before.data()
         after = after.data()` is triggering a change and causing it to fire twice? Try using a different variable name there.

Comment: What is the minimal code in `reservationAccepted` with which you can reproduce the problem? I.e. comment out everything that can't be related, if you can then still reproduce it, show us that minimal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved. I forgot to deploy my new code. In the old one, I used 2 `.set()` methods instead of one `.update()` on the client to update the reservation, which caused separate `.onUpdate` triggerings in Cloud Functions.